# Suppress/Hide push notifications in iOS when the app is running

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

I receive push notifications on certain events from a notification server we have.

1. I *do* want these notification alerts to appear when the app is *not* active in the background/foreground
2. I *don't* want the notification alert to appear when the app *is* active in the background (foreground not a problem since the notification doesn't show anyway). I want to show my own **local** notification, only.

Is there any way to do this from code? Basically I want to hide the remote push notification and instead show a local notification when my app is active.

P.S - The notification server sending silent notifications is not an option - the server does not know when our app is running/not running. There is no communication between the app and this server.

Comment: No there isn't any way to do this in code if I understand well your goal. The push alert will be delivered by the system before delegate methods like "didReceiveRemoteNotification".

Comment: What does "active in the background" mean? In the general case (there are a few limited exceptions), once you're in the background, past the grace period provided by iOS, your app is suspended.

Comment: Yes, I meant this grace period in which the app can run in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can notify your application first and then show a local notification with that. To perform this you can simply send `content-available` notification from server. This makes your app notified and then you can decide on showing local notification or not.

Comment: But if the app is not running, I do want the notification to be shown by the system. Especially because didReceiveRemoteNotification withFetchHandler is not always going to be called,  so it will not wake my app up in all cases.